# Removing the [ar] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag

[This question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47433/31410) used to have a tag called [ar](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ar). I'm assuming this was a mistake, so I edited it out of the tags. Would it be possible to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero question tags are removed automatically.